# Why my function can't read passed parameters as expectation in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I use a given postId to fetch all the comments for the post, and I expect to use a saveComments function to set the array of loaded comments into the post id.

So I passed two parameters, postId(should be a number value), and loadedComments(should be an array of comments).

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetchCommentsForPostId(postId)
      .then( loadedComments => {
        saveComments(postId, loadedComments);
      });
    },
    []
  );
```

However, when I print the value to check if passed parameters correct. I realize that the first one is good, it's an id for post. But the second one, the comments, it's also an id value. I think it should be an array.

```
  function saveCommentsForPostId(postId, comments) {

    console.log(postId); // correct id number, eg. 1
    console.log(comments); // incorrect, I think it should be an array of comments, but it is same as postId
    ...
  }
```

And then, I tried another way. I make my two parameters as an object into calling function.

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetchCommentsForPostId(postId)
      .then( loadedComments => {
        saveComments({postId, loadedComments});
      });
    },
    []
  );
```

Now, the postId is still correct. However, the comments is the whole object I passed in. It is like {postId: 1, loadedComments: Array(5)}. How could it be a whole object? I think it should be a pure array.

```
  function saveCommentsForPostId(postId, comments) {

    console.log(postId); // correct id number, eg. 1
    console.log(comments); // it is an object, eg. {postId: 1, loadedComments: Array(5)}. Why it is an object? I think it should be just an array.

    ...
  }
```

After tried out a lot of ways, the only working way is I make parameters as an object, and get the array I want use:

```
comments['loadedComments'] // this is the comment array I actually want
```

I'm super confused about it. Anyone could explain the logic behind it? Thanks in advance!

*** update

```
export function fetchCommentsForPostId(postId) {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    // This inserts a 2 second delay so we can easily see a spinner at work
    setTimeout( resolve, 2000);
  })
  .then(
    () => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
  )
  .catch( () => Promise.reject('networkError') )
  .then( response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
    return Promise.reject('serviceError');
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for fetchCommentsForPostId please?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have posted my fetchCommentsForPostId function at the end of my question! @Luiz Avila

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure what else you are doing but this seems to work:

```js
function fetchCommentsForPostId(postId) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // This inserts a 2 second delay so we can easily see a spinner at work
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  }).then(() =>
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`, {
        method: "GET",
      })
    )
    .catch(() => Promise.reject("networkError"))
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      return Promise.reject("serviceError");
    });
}

function saveCommentsForPostId(postId, comments) {
  console.log("postId:", postId);
  console.log("comments:", comments);
}

function doStuff(postId) {
  fetchCommentsForPostId(postId).then((loadedComments) => {
    saveCommentsForPostId(postId, loadedComments);
  });
}

doStuff(1);
```